# PowerShell: How to run a powershell script on a remote machine using WMI

Tags: powershell, wmi, invoke-command, get-wmiobject, wmi-service

To be specific: I want to run a powershell script on a remote windows server, but I can connect to this server using WMI only.

I used, for example, `Get-Wmiobject` to get some data like the running processes, but I failed after a lot of searching, to find a way to run a powershell script block on this remote one. One of the commands that I found is `Invoke-Command` but this one uses the winRM which is not opened to that remote server.

So, it is NOT allowed to run a powershell script on a remote server using WMI? I didn't find a clear and a direct answer for that.

Comment: That is not what WMI is used for

Comment: Thank you, but what is the main use for it?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

Consider using [`psexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) as an alternative to PowerShell remoting for executing arbitrary commands.

---

The list of PowerShell commands that support targeting remote machines *without* relying on PowerShell remoting is limited (see below); they *may* all be WMI-based (I'm not sure), and they're focused on *retrieving and manipulating remote resources* (as WMI is in general) rather than providing the ability to *execute arbitrary commands*.

<sup>**Update**: [Alberto Varga's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47384249/45375) points out that the [`Win32_Process` WMI class's `.Create` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indeed does allow creation of arbitrary processes; 
the [documentation of PowerShell's `Invoke-WmiMethod` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-wmimethod?view=powershell-5.1) even contains an example.</sup>

By contrast, `Invoke-Command`, which does offer the ability to execute arbitrary commands, *does* use PowerShell remoting, as you've discovered, which requires the WS-Management protocol, as implemented by Microsoft's WinRM service, among other prerequisites -
see [`Get-Help about_Remote_Requirements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-5.1).

The most generic of the non-remoting commands listed below is [`Invoke-WmiMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-wmimethod?view=powershell-5.1), which provides open-ended access to WMI classes and their methods.

Note, however, that Microsoft recommends using the more recent `*-Cim*` cmdlets such as `Invoke-CimMethod` in the interest of cross-platform support, and that these [CIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Information_Model_(computing))-compliant cmdlets again rely on WS-Management (WSMan) standards, as PowerShell remoting does.

---

List of PowerShell cmdlets that support targeting remote machines via `-ComputerName` *without* using PowerShell remoting, as of PSv5.1 (see [`Get-Help about_Remote_FAQ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq?view=powershell-5.1) for background info):

```
Add-Computer
Clear-EventLog
Get-EventLog
Get-HotFix
Get-Process
Get-Service
Get-WmiObject
Invoke-WmiMethod
Limit-EventLog
New-EventLog
Register-WmiEvent
Remove-Computer
Remove-EventLog
Remove-WmiObject
Rename-Computer
Restart-Computer
Set-Service
Set-WmiInstance
Show-EventLog
Stop-Computer
Test-Connection
Write-EventLog
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I tried `Invoke-WmiMethod` and I liked it. Depending on you answer, I tried many of these commands and I found that nearly all of them are WMI-based.

Comment: But unfortunately, some of them don't have a way to pass credentials to them, like `Get-Process`, `Get-Service` and Eventlog related commands, so, for example, I can use `Get-Process` directly to get the processes of a remote computer just if it is of the same credentials of my local machine, but if it isn't, I think we need to use `Invoke-Command` to pass the credentials.
Can you help me also to get files size in a specific folder through WMI? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you'll have to use `Invoke-WmiMethod` if you want to pass credentials; I suggest you try that and, should that not work, you ask a _new_ question addressing that specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done. What you want is Win32_Process and method called Create. This allows you to spawn processes on remote machines 2K3 and higher.